# Codeigniter - When select customer and show them informations

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to show customer information when I select box. I put in my view select input and when I choose to select any customer from select box, listing his estate information below. How can I that?

I show my codes below:

Estate table:

```
CREATE TABLE `estate` (
  `estateId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `estateType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'mülk türü ev, villa v.b',
  `estateCentare` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateRoom` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'adet',
  `estateSalon` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'adet',
  `estateBathroom` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'adet',
  `estateHeating` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ısıtma turu tablosu',
  `estateCity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'city Tablosu',
  `estateAddress` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateCoord` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateGarden` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'evin bahçesi var yok',
  `estateBalcony` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'balkon adet',
  `estatePackage` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `estatePackageDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `estatePackageUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateCreateDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateCreateUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateEditDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateEditUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateDue` decimal(5,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`estateId`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

cosId will be equal estateId while listing his estate information.

Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Property extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->lang->load('content', $this->session->userdata('people_lang'));

        $viewData = new stdClass();
        $viewData->customers = $this->db->get("customer")->result();

        $this->load->view('property', $viewData);
    }

}
?>
```

View:

```
<section class="panel">
<header class="panel-heading">
    PROPERTY / ESTATE
    <span class="tools pull-right">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-times"></a>
      </span>
</header>
<div class="panel-body">
    <h5>Property / Estate Management</h5>
    <div class="form-group" hidden>
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">User Who Add:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="docFileCreateUser" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata("people_id"); ?>" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h5 class=""><i class="fas fa-handshake"></i> Choose Customer:</h5>
            <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="docFileDocType" required="required">
                <option value="" readonly>Select</option>
                <?php
                foreach($customers as $customer){ if ($customer->cosStatus == 1) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $customer->cusId; ?>"><?php echo $customer->cosCode; ?> <?php echo $customer->cosName. '' .$customer->cosSurname ?></option>
                <?php } }?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="adv-table">
        <h4><?php  echo $customer->cosName.' '.$customer->cosSurname;?> |  Information of Current Payments:</h4>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <section id="no-more-tables">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf" id="dynamic-table">
                    <thead class="cf">
                    <tr>
                        <th>File ID</th>
                        <th>Customer Code</th>
                        <th>Name Surname</th>
                        <th>File Type</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Create Date</th>
                        <th>File</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    foreach($documents as $docs){ if(($customer->cusId) == ($docs->docFileCusId)){ ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="File ID"><?php  echo $docs->docFileId; ?></</td>
                            <td data-title="Customer Code"><?php  echo $customer->cosCode; ?></td>
                            <td data-title="Name Surname"><?php  echo $customer->cosName.' '.$customer->cosSurname;  ?></</td>
                            <td data-title="File Type"><?php  echo $docs->docFileDocType; ?></td>
                            <td data-title="Description"><?php  echo $docs->docFileDesc; ?></td>
                            <td data-title="Create Date"><?php  echo $docs->docFileCreateDate; ?></</td>
                            <td data-title="File"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'upload/file/customer/'.$docs->docFileDirectory;?>" download><?php  echo $docs->docFileDirectory; ?></a> <i class="fa fa-download"></i></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the OnChange function on your selector:

```
<select onChange="showInfo(this.value);" class="js-example-basic-single" name="docFileDocType" required="required">
```

JavaScript:

```
function showInfo(str){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: str },
        url: "<?=base_url('property/getInfo');?>",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#divInfo').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Controller (getInfo):

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Property extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->lang->load('content', $this->session->userdata('people_lang'));

        $viewData = new stdClass();
        $viewData->customers = $this->db->get("customer")->result();

        $this->load->view('property', $viewData);
    }

    public function getInfo(){
        $id = $this->input->post('id');

        $viewData->estate = $this->db->get_where("estate",['estateId'=>$id])->result();

        $this->load->view('getInfo', $viewData);
    }

}
?>
```

View (getInfo) "Small part.":

```
<tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
    <th>Column 6</th>
    <th>Column 7</th>
    <th>Column 8</th>
    <th>Column 9</th>
    <th>Column 10</th>
    <th>Column 11</th>
    <th>Column 12</th>
    <th>Column 13</th>
    <th>Column 14</th>
    <th>Column 15</th>
    <th>Column 16</th>
    <th>Column 17</th>
    <th>Column 18</th>
    <th>Column 19</th>
    <th>Column 20</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($estates as $estate){?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateId; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateType; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateCentare; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateRoom; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateSalon; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateBathroom; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateHeating; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateCity; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateAddress; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateCoord; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateGarden; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateBalcony; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estatePackage; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estatePackageDate; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estatePackageUser; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateCreateDate; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateCreateUser; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateEditDate; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateEditUser; ?></</td>
        <td><?php  echo $estate->estateDue; ?></</td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

New View (property):

```
<section class="panel">
    <header class="panel-heading">
        PROPERTY / ESTATE
        <span class="tools pull-right">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-times"></a>
          </span>
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h5>Property / Estate Management</h5>
        <div class="form-group" hidden>
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">User Who Add:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="docFileCreateUser" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata("people_id"); ?>" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h5 class=""><i class="fas fa-handshake"></i> Choose Customer:</h5>
                <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="docFileDocType" required="required">
                    <option value="" readonly>Select</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($customers as $customer){ if ($customer->cosStatus == 1) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $customer->cusId; ?>"><?php echo $customer->cosCode; ?> <?php echo $customer->cosName. '' .$customer->cosSurname ?></option>
                    <?php } }?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="adv-table">
            <h4><?php  echo $customer->cosName.' '.$customer->cosSurname;?> |  Information of Current Payments:</h4>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <section id="no-more-tables">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf" id="dynamic-table">
                        <thead class="cf">
                        <tr>
                            <th>File ID</th>
                            <th>Customer Code</th>
                            <th>Name Surname</th>
                            <th>File Type</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Create Date</th>
                            <th>File</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php
                        foreach($documents as $docs){ if(($customer->cusId) == ($docs->docFileCusId)){ ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td data-title="File ID"><?php  echo $docs->docFileId; ?></</td>
                                <td data-title="Customer Code"><?php  echo $customer->cosCode; ?></td>
                                <td data-title="Name Surname"><?php  echo $customer->cosName.' '.$customer->cosSurname;  ?></</td>
                                <td data-title="File Type"><?php  echo $docs->docFileDocType; ?></td>
                                <td data-title="Description"><?php  echo $docs->docFileDesc; ?></td>
                                <td data-title="Create Date"><?php  echo $docs->docFileCreateDate; ?></</td>
                                <td data-title="File"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'upload/file/customer/'.$docs->docFileDirectory;?>" download><?php  echo $docs->docFileDirectory; ?></a> <i class="fa fa-download"></i></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } } ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divInfo"></div>
</section>
```

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: But I want to get all info from Estate Table. I will try it thanks.

Comment: And customer table has no cusId. So i want to equal these function cusId=estateId while listing information from estate table.

Comment: Can you share the model?

Comment: I do not use model. I just use Controller.

Comment: Okay, I moment.

Comment: Every time you change the checkbox, do you want what information to appear, from which table?

Comment: Just to understand better, cosID = estateId, that is, every time you change the selector, the system has to make a query inside the estate table, is that it?

Comment: I want to show the information from Estate Table according to equality of cusId from customer table = estateId from estate table.

Comment: In your view I add: <div id="divInfo"></div>

Comment: I edited all the code again, take a look please and see if this is what you want...

Comment: I was able to help then? You’re Welcome.

Comment: Can you see this topic too please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179130/codeigniter-how-to-show-name-from-other-table-using-id

Comment: Yes, I see. No problem